# Detect hardware keyboard events with UIInputViewController

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I need a way to handle events happening and modifying text on `UITextInputDelegate` when running an App keyboard extension.

currently I can handle keyboard arrows, because those change the cursor position, but key pressed does not change anything, apparently.

Probably there is none by design, but I would like to know, I tried with

```
@protocol UITextInputDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)selectionWillChange:(nullable id <UITextInput>)textInput;
- (void)selectionDidChange:(nullable id <UITextInput>)textInput;
- (void)textWillChange:(nullable id <UITextInput>)textInput;
- (void)textDidChange:(nullable id <UITextInput>)textInput;
```